# Telegram Bot останавливается каждые 60 секунд Heroku

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, telegram-bot, node-modules

Меня зовут Григорий, и я - front-end разработчик, но по воле судьбы пришлось столкнутся с разработкой чат бота в Telegram.

Я написал полностью работоспособного бота, но для его функционирования мне приходилось постоянно запускать сервер. Платить мне не особо хочется за сервера, по этому решил залить бота на Github и "оживил" через Heroku. Но проблема в том что работает приложение в Heroku всего 60 секунд, после чего оно выдаёт следующее:

```
2020-06-20T17:02:59.205971+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2020-06-20T17:02:59.226074+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2020-06-20T17:02:59.322476+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2020-06-20T17:02:59.358685+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Код бота:

```
let TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api'),
    token = '{здесь мой токен}';

let bot = new TelegramBot(token, {
    polling: true,
    none_stop: true
});

let mainOptions = {
    "reply_markup": {
        "keyboard": [
            ["Hi "],
            ["Keyboard ⌨️"],
            ["I'm robot "]
        ]
    }
};

bot.on('message', (msg) => {
    if (msg.text === '/start') {
        bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, "Добро пожаловать в главное меню бота!", mainOptions);        
    }
    
});



bot.on('message', (msg) => {
    let hi = "Hi ",
        keyboard = "Keyboard ⌨️",
        robot = "I'm robot ";
    if (msg.text === hi) {
        bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, "Привет " + msg.from.first_name + "!", {
            "reply_markup": {
                "keyboard": [
                    ["Next option"],
                    ["<- Back"]
                ]
            }
        });
    } else if (msg.text === keyboard) {
        bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, "Да, поклацал кнопочки, бывает");
    } else if (msg.text === robot) {
        bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, "А я типа не робот");
    } else if (msg.text === '<- Back') {
        bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, text = "Вы вернулись в Главное меню!", mainOptions);
    } else if(msg.chat.id == 'айдишник') {
        bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, text = "Ой иди в жопу я обиделся на тебя :(");
    } else {
        if (msg.text === '/start') {
            return false;
        } else {
            bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, "Я пока что не настолько умён. Отправил ответ админу.\n\nBot is running on Node.js(v12.18.1) + Hiroku + Github.\nMade by @MrGregorK", mainOptions);
            bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id = 'айдишник', '<b>Сообщение от</b>: ' + msg.from.first_name + ' ' + msg.from.last_name + '\n<b>Username:</b> @' + msg.from.username + '\n<b>User chat ID</b>: ' + msg.from.id + '\n----------------\n' + msg.text, {
                parse_mode: "HTML"
            });
        }

    }
});
```

и на этом вся работа бота заканчивается.
Как сделать так чтобы бот работал всё время? Можете подсказать что читать, что смотреть? Нужно чтобы бот работал всё время.

Comment: Мне кажется, бесплатные сервера не готовы терпеть поллинг. Разберитесь с вебхуками)

Comment: Спасибо, постараюсь!)

Answer (score 0):

Если бот в фоне не собирает данные то можно подключить вэбхук. Если же надо чтобы бот работал постоянно, то пингуй свою страницу на хероку каждые минут 20 и будет тебе счастье.

```js
setInterval(() => {
  http.get("http://yourapp.herokuapp.com/", (res) => {})
}, 20 * 60 * 1000)
```